# Mustache Partials in PHP - How do I use them?

Tags: php, mustache

CONTEXT:

I have read as much Mustache documentation as possible but I cannot get my head around how to use partials or even whether I am using Mustache in the correct way.

The code below is working correctly. My problem is that I have three Mustache files that I want to include and render all at once.

I am guessing that this is what partials are meant for but I cannot seem to make it work.

---

QUESTIONS:

How I would get partials working in this context so that my three Mustache files are being loaded and are all being passed the $data variable?

Should I be using file_get_contents in this manner for the template? I have seen Mustache functions being used in its place but I cannot find extensive enough documentation to get it working.

---

ENV:

I am using the latest version of Mustache from https://github.com/bobthecow/mustache.php

My files are:
index.php ( below )
template.mustache
template1.mustache
template2.mustache
class.php

---

CODE:

```
// This is index.php
// Require mustache for our templates
require 'mustache/src/Mustache/Autoloader.php';
Mustache_Autoloader::register();

// Init template engine
$m = new Mustache_Engine;

// Set up our templates
$template   = file_get_contents("template.mustache");

// Include the class which contains all the data and initialise it
include('class.php');
$data = new class();

    // Render the template
print $m->render( $template, $data );
```

---

THANK YOU:

Any examples of a PHP implementation of partials ( including how the necessary file structure would need to be ) would be greatly appreciated, just so I am able to get a solid understanding :)

Comment: Let me suggest this post full of examples including partials, but not including file structures, as this is up to you/your framework: http://coenraets.org/blog/2011/12/tutorial-html-templates-with-mustache-js/

Comment: Thank you. Really I am looking for a PHP implementation with examples using templates stored in separate files.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The simplest is to use the "filesystem" template loader:

```
<?php
// This is index.php
// Require mustache for our templates
require 'mustache/src/Mustache/Autoloader.php';
Mustache_Autoloader::register();

// Init template engine
$m = new Mustache_Engine(array(
    'loader' => new Mustache_Loader_FilesystemLoader(dirname(__FILE__))
));

// Include the class which contains all the data and initialise it
include('class.php');
$data = new class();

// Render the template
print $m->render('template', $data);
```

Then, assuming your `template.mustache` looks something like this:

```
{{> template2 }}
{{> template3 }}
```

The `template2.mustache` and `template3.mustache` templates would be automatically loaded from the current directory when needed.

Note that this loader is used for both the original template and the partials. If you have your partials stored in a subdirectory, for example, you can add a second loader specifically for partials:

```
<?php
$m = new Mustache_Engine(array(
    'loader'          => new Mustache_Loader_FilesystemLoader(dirname(__FILE__).'/views'),
    'partials_loader' => new Mustache_Loader_FilesystemLoader(dirname(__FILE__).'/views/partials')
));
```

There's more info on these and other `Mustache_Engine` options on [the Mustache.php wiki](https://github.com/bobthecow/mustache.php/wiki).

Comment: Thank you very much for this clarification. Mustache is the first templating system that I have used, just needed some clarification on the file structure. Thanks again :)

Comment: No problem. I added a template loading page to the Mustache.php wiki, hopefully this will help clarify as well — https://github.com/bobthecow/mustache.php/wiki/Template-Loading

Comment: Took me a bit to get this rolling but works great. This is going to simplify our platform templating greatly. Thanks from 2017!